# Making Fb and twitter widgets responsive

Tags: responsive-design

How to make Fb and Twitter widgets responsive across all devices? I tried to set the iframe width to 100% but when I look it in smart phones, It stretches the layout which leads to the horizontal scroll bar. This happens to youtube videos also.

Comment: Please ask a more specific questions and give a clearer example of what you're trying to do. Stackoverflow is effort in = effort out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For twitter! The easiest solution i've found is through css. Edit the .twtr-doc class to whathave a width of 100%.

For FB (assuming you talking about like box) I changed the first width to auto and the second one (inline css) to 100%
I'll be using Coca Cola as an example...

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcocacola&amp;width=auto&amp;height=395&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=false&amp;appId=176993455739426" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:395px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
#twitter-widget-0{
   width: 100% !important;  
}
```

Comment: This works well for twitter and media queries can be used to make it full responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter is fairly responsive of it's own. But what about aspect ratio? It boils down to the same problem as with youtube vids. Both are Iframes.

Now I should credit some people with coming up with this for youtube but I've forgotten who. Sorry. At any rate it is also used by [Tod Moto's Fluidvids.](http://toddmotto.com/fluid-and-responsive-youtube-and-vimeo-videos-with-fluidvids-js/)

So here's the trick. You place the iframe of either youtube or the twitter widget inside a div (or any block element). 
give it these CSS values:

```
div {
position: relative;
padding-top: SEE BELOW
width: 100%; }
```

then apply this to the Iframe:

```
div iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; }
```

at SEE BELOW you should write your aspect ratio. You can compute this by deviding width by height and multiplying with 100%. Which is lovely easy in Sass, if you haven't discovered that yet.

My html looks like this, btw. The twitter javascript file is in not inline because I Ajax the widget and inline scripts dont run when Ajaxed.

```
<aside>
    <div>
        <a class="twitter-timeline" height="570" href="https://twitter.com/PartosNL" data-widget-id="520500579978596352">Tweets van @PartosNL</a>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/twitter.js"></script>
        <br class="clear">
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.twitter-tweet{
   width: 100% !important;  
}
```

use class instead of id #twitter-widget-0 because if you add more than one twitter feed in your website,it selects only the first tweet and add css to it.

Answer (score 0):

For Twitter try:

Step 1: 
Download Twitter's widget js file and put it in "YOUR_LOCAL_PATH/js"

---

Step 2:
Modifying the widget call script as so:
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="YOUR_LOCAL_PATH/js/twitter.widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
You should see that I have deleted the "p" variable and the protocol declaration and I'm pointing towards a local copy of Twitter's widget js file.

---

Step 3:
Use something like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to make the code inside the widgets.js file readable. After that copy that code inside "YOUR_LOCAL_PATH/js/twitter.widgets.js"

---

Step 4.1 : Look for and modify like I suggested below: 
`dimensions: {
            DEFAULT_HEIGHT: "600",
            DEFAULT_WIDTH: "100", // modify this to be 100 - like 100%
            NARROW_WIDTH: "100", // modify this to be 100 - like 100%
            MIN_WIDTH: "100", // modify this to be 100 - like 100%
            MIN_HEIGHT: "200", 
            WIDE_MEDIA_PADDING: 81,
            NARROW_MEDIA_PADDING: 16,
            WIDE_MEDIA_PADDING_CL: 60,
            NARROW_MEDIA_PADDING_CL: 12 },`

Step 4.2 :  Look for and modify like I suggested below:
From this: .frame.style.minWidth = s.dimensions.MIN_WIDTH + "px"  to this
.frame.style.minWidth = s.dimensions.MIN_WIDTH + "%"

---

Step 5. Congratulations, you now have a responsive twitter widget! If they release new versions of the widget, just remake the steps  I suggested!

Comment: This solves the problem but then you'd be using a custom JS so your implementation may break in the future if Twitter changes anything on their side. @Guiaemedica Gozum's answer works with a few lines of CSS meaning that media queries could be used to full responsiveness.